# Install Gh-ost On EC2 server

Tags: migration, amazon-rds, ghost-blog

I am trying to install GH-OST on a (Linux) Server.
I did the following:

**sudo yum install -y git gcc-c++ make cmake openssl-devel**

**git clone https://github.com/github/gh-ost.git**

**cd gh-ost**
**cmake.**

- GET ERROR
  CMake Error: The source directory "///temp/gh-ost" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
  Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.

that I check if the installation was successful I get

**gh-ost --version**

bash: gh-ost: command not found

Thank you

try to script Build.sh
from gh-ost folder

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.